# Not able to animate solid gauge chart with Angular Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, highcharts

I'm using Highchart with Angular and have used the ng dependency for highchart library from [here](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) butI'm not able to animate the guage chart, I want to animate the chart as in the [OFFICIAL PAGE](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid) I've made sure to add the animate factors but not able to make it work

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6hxaB/52/)

```
  animation: {
                    duration: 5000,
                    easing: "linear"
              }
```

Please help me in animate the chart,

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any wrapper? If i.e highcharts-ng, you should contact with the authors of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same issue and found that installing the lastest version of highcharts solved my problem (>4.1.4).

Hope this will help someone, your fiddle now works btw.

Comment: This certainly does the trick for me. I upgraded to the latest version from  Highcharts JS v4.0.1 to  Highcharts JS v4.1.9 and the loading animation works great now. Thanks for the tip!